# static_transform_publisher and robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a bit confused about the `static_transform_publisher` and the `robot_state_publisher` (or at least I think I am).
So we are setting up a robot with sensor at all, and before we used the urdf approach we were using the `static_transform_publisher` to get the TF between sensors.

Now we want to use the urdf approach, i.e. `robot_state_publisher`. This is also publishing TF.
So this should be now our source for tf, right? No need for the `static_transform_publisher`? (I think it will even interfere)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273507/static_transform_publisher-and-robot_state_publisher/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now we want to use the urdf approach, i.e. `robot_state_publisher`. This is also publishing TF.
> So this should be now our source for tf, right? No need for the `static_transform_publisher`? (I think it will even interfere)

In short: yes, TF frames should preferably have only one backing publisher.

If you have a urdf, `robot_state_publisher` (RSP) can do that for you, no need for `static_transform_publisher` (STP).

You're not required to use RSP though, you can use URDF and still use STP as well.

One advantage of the RSP over STP is that the former will listen to `JointState` msgs (on the `joint_states` topic) and update the frames it knows about (from your urdf) using FK. That is something STP cannot do.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:
Btw: we have an expression here in the lab: if you are using ROS for your robot and don't have a urdf, you're "doing it wrong".

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-10-19**:
haha totally agree! I like your lab! I just wanted to clarify this as it is not 100% clear from the documentation. Thx!